# How to order lightning experience tabs?

Tags: lightning-experience, tab

[image: tab]

How can I order tabs in Salesforce Lightning Experience app? Please note that some of these tabs are default object tabs and some are lightning app pages.

Comment: Check if this can help you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150055/can-we-change-sequence-of-tabs-in-lightning/150058#150058

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rearrange tab order, your app should be of type "Lightning"

Please follow these steps:

1. Goto Setup Home
2. Open App Manager
3. Search for your app
4. Look at the list - if at the column "APP TYPE" it says "Classic" - you need to click on the drop-down arrow and select "Upgrade", then on the popup select a new app name and click "Upgrade".

[image]
5. Now your "APP TYPE" (the newly upgraded one or the old one) is "Lightning", click on the drop-down arrow and select "Edit".

[image]

6. A new page opens - select the "SELECT ITEMS" tab and choose and rearrange your app's tabs:

[image]

Hope this helps!